# Cant access a remote server due mistake by setting firewall rule

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

**I need help due a my silly mistake!**

So for long time i have a dedicate server hosted by register.it

Usually i access remotly to this server (Windows 2008 server) by Terminal Server.
Today i wanted to block one site that continually send request to my server.

So i was adding a new rule in the firewall (the native firewall on windows 2008 server), as i did many time, but this time, probably i was sleeping with my brain i add a **general rules that stop everything**!

So i cant access to the server anymore, as no any users can browse the sites, nothing is working because this rule block everything.

I know that is a silly mistake, no need to tell me :) so please what i can do ?

The only 1 thing that my provider let me is reboot the server by his control panel, but this not help me in any way because the firewall block me again.

i have administrator username and password, so what i really can do ?

there are some trick some tecnique, some expert guru that can help me in this very bad situation ?

**UPDATE**
i follow the Tony suggest and i did a NMAP to check if some ports are open but look like all closed:

**NMAP RESULT**

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-05-29 22:32 W. Europe Daylight Time
NSE: Loaded 93 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 22:32
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 22:33, 13.00s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 22:33
Scanning xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [1000 ports]
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 29.00% done; ETC: 22:34 (0:01:16 remaining)
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 58.00% done; ETC: 22:34 (0:00:44 remaining)
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 22:34, 104.39s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 22:34
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Retrying OS detection (try #2) against xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Initiating Traceroute at 22:34
Completed Traceroute at 22:35, 6.27s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 11 hosts. at 22:35
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 11 hosts. at 22:35, 13.00s elapsed
NSE: Script scanning xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Initiating NSE at 22:35
Completed NSE at 22:35, 0.00s elapsed
Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx are filtered
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   ...
... ...
13  ... 30

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Read data files from: D:\Program Files\Nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 145.08 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 2116 (96.576KB) | Rcvd: 61 (4.082KB)
```

**Question: The provider locally can access by username and password ?**

Comment: This could help you(on the future) :P http://www.research.ibm.com/physicsofinfo/members/teleportation.htm

Comment: @nwilder You are funny but sure i will love to use the teleport also for other better target and destination :)

Comment: will the hoster not support you in this case?

Answer (score 6):

If you can't get in remotely you will have to get your provider to fix the problem for you by connecting locally.

Comment: @lain That's clear and evident and thanks for your answer, i was thinking if exist some that i can do by have the administrator privilege in hand. There are backdoor ? vulnerability ? something that i can do ? poor me really ;(

Comment: Not likely to work but you could do an nmap scan against it to see what holes are open. If you hoster can't help this may be your only chance.  but on the other hand if you really did shut down all ports then this might not work!  I'd hire a hacker to see what they could do...

Comment: @tonyroth thanks for your suggestion, i download and perform a NMAP and i post the result in the question

Comment: @LMIT if it's clear and evident why are you wasting your time here ?

Comment: ops @lain :) i m not wasting my time here because i tried to consult all the expert people on here to have a chance to understand better and try to solve or try to get more info as i got about NMAP no ? isnt this the purpose of this site ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your provider [does not provide remote console access to its servers](http://help.register.it/faq/register.it/eng/server/dedicated_servers/index.html#id478). This means your only option is to request that they reinstall the operating system. Once it is reinstalled, you can restore from your backups.

You may wish to shop for another server provider who offers remote console access to their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer as a suggestion for the future.

Have some sort of additional way into your machine. IE: LogMeIn, TeamViewer, VNC, anything that causes the connection to established out from the server to the interent should prevent firewall mistakes like this one from preventing your access.

Comment: yes i accept your suggestion for the future, this mistake teach me well